# Need to read from a txt file in the assets folder in android studio

Tags: java, android

My buddy and I are writing a simple app in Android Studio. When you push a button, a new activity opens with the name of the button you pushed and displays the text in that file.

I have the code that generates the first set of buttons (these are hard coded), and I can get the name of the buttons pushed. My trouble is reading the text file and displaying the contents. Each line in the text file is a word that needs to be the text value of a button. I can't hard code the words because they can change often.

Example; On the main activity you push the button labeled "Round", it sends you to a page that has all the words in the text file named "round" listed as buttons.

I asked this question earlier, but it was put on hold as too vague.
I hope this is more clear.

Here's the code I'm using, but need the code to read the file. This is not working right.

I can't get it to display even the first line. The file contents are this ---
Pipe
Elbow
Reducer
Tap on flat
EC

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```java
public class test extends Activity {
    int counter = 0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        counter = 0;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblLayoutContent);

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("round.txt")));

            // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
            String mLine;
            while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
                    TableRow tblRow = new TableRow(this);
                    tblRow.setPadding(5, 30, 5, 5);
                    table.addView(tblRow);
                    int NUM_COL = 3;

                    for (int col = 0; col != NUM_COL; col++) {
                        Button btn = new Button(this);
                        btn.setText(mLine);
                        tblRow.addView(btn);
                        NUM_COL++;

                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //log the exception
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //log the exception
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an image of my structure:

[image: Here's an image of my structure]

Comment: What do you mean by "not working right"? What is the output you are getting right now?

Comment: Nothing. No output at all. The txt file is in the assets folder.

Comment: Here's the XML for tableLayoutContent     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tblLayoutContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart = "true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        >
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: I added e.printStackTrace(); to all my catch blocks to see if I could get some more info. No luck No errors are being thrown.

Comment: Okay, did get this after looking a bit..    System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: round.txt

Comment: Can you show your directory structure, where the round.txt file is located.

Comment: your assets seem to have no file extension. try to rename them or load the file "round" and not "round.txt"

Comment: I renamed them, tried it, no joy. Then removed the .txt from both the code and files, no joy. This one is really getting me.

Comment: What error did you get after renaming?

Comment: No error, nothing changed from before. It is not doing anything. Just a blank screen. Renaming those had no effect on anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I found the answer. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.
Here it is

```
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("round.txt");

        // We guarantee that the available method returns the total
        // size of the asset...  of course, this does mean that a single
        // asset can't be more than 2 gigs.
        int size = is.available();

        // Read the entire asset into a local byte buffer.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();

        // Convert the buffer into a string.
        String text = new String(buffer);

        // Finally stick the string into the text view.
        // Replace with whatever you need to have the text into.

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText(text);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Should never happen!
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Reworked the code and this is the one that works.
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("round.txt");

```
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        // Finally stick the string into the text of the button.

        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblLayoutContent);

        String line = reader.readLine();
        int lineLength = (line.length());
        while (line != null){

            TableRow tblRow = new TableRow(this);
            tblRow.setPadding(5, 30, 5, 5);
            table.addView(tblRow);


            for (int col = 0; col < NUM_COL; col++) {
                Button btn = new Button(this);
                btn.setTextSize(14);

                btn.setText(line);
                tblRow.addView(btn);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        };

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Should never happen!
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

U can read from a file, line by line like this:

```
        String filename = "filename.txt";
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;    
        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                    (this.getAssets().open(filename), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
              //add the lines in some arraylist if you want to set them.
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin , we can do as

```
val string = requireContext().assets.open("round.txt").bufferedReader().use {
            it.readText()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... add **getResources()**

```
reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(getResources().getAssets().open("round.txt")));
```

Comment: Tried this. Sorry, but still no output at all. Just a blank screen.